# How to Cancel the running Job in a dialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

Currently using SWT dialog and created a progress bar along with progressBar cancellation.

```java
 progressBarCancelButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    job.cancel();   
            }

        });
```

When I click the Cancel Button the running jobs need to stop.
But I am not able to cancel the job. Is there any best way to stop the running jobs.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

`cancel` is the correct method to call the cancel a `Job`.

To make this work the `run` method of the `Job` must check the `isCanceled` method of the `IProgressMonitor` regularly.

So the `run` method needs to be something like:

```java
@Override
protected IStatus run(final IProgressMonitor monitor)
{
  monitor.beginTask(....);

  try {
     for (;;) {
        ... do a small amount of work

        if (monitor.isCanceled()) {
          ... clean up
          return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
        }
      }
   }
  finally
   {
     monitor.done();
   }


  return Status.OK_STATUS;
}
```